# How to define new port in c for microcontroler

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, pic, mikroc

I need to define virtual port or variable bind with [porta.1,porta.2,portc.1,portc.2]
Because some pins of all available port in micro controller(PIC18F4550) in in use and i have not any free port;

I need help in C programming for embeded(mikrocForPIC is my IDE).
I need something like below:

```
#define myport=[Porta.1+Porta.2+Portc.1+Portc.2]

.
.
.
```

and use for:

```
myport++;
myport<<1;
```

I remember it was able but i cant remember what is true syntax!?

please help

thanks

Comment: Instead of posting some confusing pseudocode, can you please state what you want to accomplish in plain English?  Then we could help you with what the code constructs could be.

Comment: Do you agee that this is strictly denpendent on microcontroller and compiler. You didn't specify nothing of them.

Comment: @Harper it's tagged with [pic] and [mikroc], so I think that tiny portion is defined...

Comment: some people are too smart some people is too stupid,Dont wory !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a specific BIT in one of the available port, you use (In MikroC), 
sbit PORTA1 at RA1_bit;

sbit is a compiler reserved word which means that you specify a single bit in a byte.

"PortA1" could be anything. You use this to give a name to the bit you specified.

at is a compiler reserved word, gives the path of the name you created.

RA1_bit is the actual definition of the PORTA-1 bit in MikroC, exemple a PIC.

You can't virtually "create" a port which is not available on the MCU. You can define a variable that is equal to the value of the port.

```
 //#define PortValue PORTA
```

PortValue, in the code, will always have the same value as the actual physical "PortA".

OR, in the code, define a variable, let's say unsigned char, which is equal to the value of the port. You'll then be able to play around with your variable.

UC ucPort;

```
ucPort = PORTA; //Specific to MIKROC for PIC. May be different in other compilers.
```